# CyberLink PowerDirector : You have to be the administrator to activate the system. Only the administrator has the right to activate the program

Tags: installation, windows-10, entra-id, activation

I received the following error while attempting to Open/Run CyberLink PowerDirector for the first time:

```
You have to be the administrator to activate the system. Only the administrator has the right to activate the program
```

This happened while I was logged in as an administrator, and persisted even when I manually ran the application "Run As Administrator".

The administrator user in question was logged into the Windows 10 machine as an Office 365 username.

Answer (score 2):

When logging into Windows 10 as a "Microsoft Work or School Account", there appears to be something different about the an Azure AD account works. Based on what I've seen, I think it may be based on the way the username is referenced, but in any case it breaks things. [Vmware is one I can think of immediately](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/516627).

In any case, try running the application the first time as a "Local" user who is an admin, rather than an AzureAD user.

e.g. Create an admin user and run the program as that user.

1. This Computer -> (Rigt-Click) -> Manage -> Local Users and Groups -> Users -> (Right-Click) -> New User (Create the User)
2. Find the user you just created, double-click on him, go to "Member Of" and add the "administrators group.
3. Navigate to the folder where there is a short-cut to the program and right-click on the program with the SHIFT key pressed and choose "Run as a different user".
4. Enter the username in the following format and the password as you set it:

   .\username

The program should run now.